# N-Bonnaci sequence calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci-sequence

The code calculates a n-bonnaci sequence to a certain number, based on the user's input. It then can print it to a file and/or print it to the console.

The `calculateSequence` function calculates the sequence. The first loop fills the sequence with ones (0, 1, 1, 2...). Next, it calculates the value of the current number, using `crrntVlue` as a placeholder, and using `i` as the location of the value to add (a number is the sum of the preceding two numbers). `sqnceItratr` is location of the number that is being calculated.

My questions are:

1. Is there anything immediately wrong that you see in the code?
2. How can I make the code more readable/better variable names, as it was hard to understand the code while coding it?
3. How can I restructure the program to make it better?

This is one of my first Python programs, so I want to know what I might be coding 'wrong'.

```
def calculateSequence(n, amntToCalc):
    sqnceItratr = 1
    sequence = [0] * numbrsToCalc

    #Add 1's to the array(Duonacci is 1, 1, 2... Tribonacci is 1, 1, 1, 3...)
    while sqnceItratr < n:
        sequence[sqnceItratr] = 1
        sqnceItratr += 1

    #Actually Calculate the Sequence
    while sqnceItratr < numbrsToCalc:
        i = N
        #i is the location of the amount to add to crrntVlue
        #Ex: sequence[3] = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3, i is sequence[3 - 1]

        crrntVlue = 0
        while i > 0:
            #This is to calculate the actual value of a number
            #in the sequence
            crrntVlue += sequence[sqnceItratr - i]
            i -= 1
            #Count Down for the number to add to crrntValue(n-bonnacci)

        sequence[sqnceItratr] = crrntVlue
        # Add crrntValue to the array
        sqnceItratr += 1
        #Continue to the next value in the array
    return sequence

def convertInput(inputToConvert):
    inputToConvert = inputToConvert.upper()
    if inputToConvert == 'Y':
        return True
    elif inputToConvert == 'YES':
        return True
    else:
        return False

N = int(input("What do you want to n in N-bonnacci to be? \n"))
numbrsToCalc = int(input("How many digits do you want to calculate? \n This should probably be bigger than n \n"))
sequence = calculateSequence(N, numbrsToCalc)

userInput1 = convertInput(input("Do you want to write it to a file? \n"))
sequencePosition = 0
if userInput1 == True:
    file = open("Seqence.txt", "w")
    while sequencePosition < len(sequence):
        file.write(str(sequencePosition + 1) + ': ' + str(sequence[sequencePosition]) + '\n')
        sequencePosition += 1
    file.close()

userInput2 = convertInput(input("Do you want to print it out? \n"))
if userInput2 == True:
    sequencePosition = 0
    while sequencePosition < len(sequence):
        print(str(sequencePosition + 1) + ': ' + str(sequence[sequencePosition]))
        sequencePosition += 1
```

Comment: If this is not actually the case, I suggest you use Pylint in order to check if your code is respecting the coding standards of Python, amongs other things. 

see http://www.pylint.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **Algorithm**

  Looks like you are doing too much. The recurrence can be greatly simplified:

  \$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n-k+1} + a_{n-k}\$, and

  \$a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n-1} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n-k+1}\$, so

  \$a_{n+1} = a_{n} + (a_{n-1} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n-k+1}) = a_{n} + (a_{n} - a_{n-k})\$

  meaning that the next `k`-bonacchi number is just

  ```
    sequence[n+1] = 2*sequence[n] + sequence[n-k]
  ```
- **Naming**

  Honestly, names like `sqnceItratr` and `crrntVlue` are more than unreadable. Don't abbreviate so aggressively. In this particular case I'd say that `n` fits much better than `sqnceItratr`.
- **Separation of concerns**

  `calculateSequence` initialize the sequence and produces the rest of it in a single call. It doesn't look right. I recommend to split the solution in `initialize`, and `compute_next` calls, along the lines of

  ```
  sequence = initialize(N)
  for n in range(N, limit):
      value = compute_next(sequence, N)
      sequence.append(value)
  ```

Comment: So sequence[2 + 1] = 2 * sequence[2] + sequence[n-k],                       sequence[3] = 2  * 1 + 2 - 2, if the sequence is 0, 1, 1, 2?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a quick look.

```
def calculateSequence(n, amntToCalc):
    sqnceItratr = 1
```

Why are you starting iteration at `1` instead of `0`?

```
    sequence = [0] * numbrsToCalc
```

`amntToCalc` is a bit short. Maybe write `result_length` or something?

```
    #Add 1's to the array(Duonacci is 1, 1, 2... Tribonacci is 1, 1, 1, 3...)
    while sqnceItratr < n:
        sequence[sqnceItratr] = 1
        sqnceItratr += 1
```

This loop can be replaced with `sequence[1:n] = [1] * (n - 1)`.

```
    sequence[1:n] = [1] * (n-1)
    sqnceItratr = n
```

A bit shorter. (I'm hoping to get rid of the `sqnceItratr` later on).

```
    #Actually Calculate the Sequence
    while sqnceItratr < numbrsToCalc:
        i = N
        #i is the location of the amount to add to crrntVlue
        #Ex: sequence[3] = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3, i is sequence[3 - 1]

        crrntVlue = 0
        while i > 0:
            #This is to calculate the actual value of a number
            #in the sequence
            crrntVlue += sequence[sqnceItratr - i]
            i -= 1
            #Count Down for the number to add to crrntValue(n-bonnacci)
```

Let's look if we can get rid of this loop a bit.

```
        crrntVlue = sum(sequence[sqnceItratr - N:sqnceItratr])
```

Glad we got rid of that loop, and replaced it with a simple sum function. Also, `N` is a global variable, we should replace that with `n` (which is passed in).

```
        crrntVlue = sum(sequence[sqnceItratr - n:sqnceItratr])
        sequence[sqnceItratr] = crrntVlue
```

We can get rid of the temporary variable.

```
        sequence[sqnceItratr] = sum(sequence[sqnceItratr - n:sqnceItratr])
```

Better. This leaves us with

```
def calculateSequence(n, amntToCalc):
    sqnceItratr = 1
    sequence = [0] * numbrsToCalc

    #Add 1's to the array(Duonacci is 1, 1, 2... Tribonacci is 1, 1, 1, 3...)
    sequence[1:n] = [1] * (n-1)
    sqnceItratr = n

    #Actually Calculate the Sequence
    while sqnceItratr < numbrsToCalc:
        sequence[sqnceItratr] = sum(sequence[sqnceItratr - n:sqnceItratr])
        # Add crrntValue to the array
        sqnceItratr += 1
        #Continue to the next value in the array
    return sequence
```

I'm not a huge fan of `while` loops myself.

```
    #Actually Calculate the Sequence
    for sqnceItratr in range(n, numbrsToCalc):
        sequence[sqnceItratr] = sum(sequence[sqnceItratr - n:sqnceItratr])
    return sequence
```

Even shorter. Now we can get rid of the `sqnceItratr` before the loop. Also drop the comments, because the code itself is now more clear.

```
def calculateSequence(n, amntToCalc):
    sequence = [0] * numbrsToCalc
    sequence[1:n] = [1] * (n-1)
    for sqnceItratr in range(n, numbrsToCalc):
        sequence[sqnceItratr] = sum(sequence[sqnceItratr - n:sqnceItratr])
    return sequence
```

Ok, the `sqnceItratr` could be renamed as well, but it's ok.

```
def convertInput(inputToConvert):
    inputToConvert = inputToConvert.upper()
    if inputToConvert == 'Y':
        return True
    elif inputToConvert == 'YES':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Oh, we can replace the two `==` with `in ('Y', 'YES')`.

```
def convertInput(inputToConvert):
    inputToConvert = inputToConvert.upper()
    if inputToConvert in ('Y', 'YES'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Even better: replace it with a simple return:

```
def convertInput(inputToConvert):
    return inputToConvert.upper() in ('Y', 'YES')
```

And now the calling code.

```
N = int(input("What do you want to n in N-bonnacci to be? \n"))
numbrsToCalc = int(input("How many digits do you want to calculate? \n This should probably be bigger than n \n"))
sequence = calculateSequence(N, numbrsToCalc)

userInput1 = convertInput(input("Do you want to write it to a file? \n"))
sequencePosition = 0
if userInput1 == True:
    file = open("Seqence.txt", "w")
    while sequencePosition < len(sequence):
        file.write(str(sequencePosition + 1) + ': ' + str(sequence[sequencePosition]) + '\n')
        sequencePosition += 1
    file.close()

userInput2 = convertInput(input("Do you want to print it out? \n"))
if userInput2 == True:
    sequencePosition = 0
    while sequencePosition < len(sequence):
        print(str(sequencePosition + 1) + ': ' + str(sequence[sequencePosition]))
        sequencePosition += 1
```

Variable names could be replaced: `userInput1` is `writeToFile`, `userInput2` is `writeToStdout`.

The code could be generalised out, writing to `file` and `sys.stdout`.

```
if writeToFile:
    with open('Seqence.txt', 'w') as f:
        writeSequence(sequence, f)
 if writeToStdout:
     writeSequence(sequence, sys.stdout)
```

(Also, instead of `f = open(...)` and `f.close()`, use `with open(...) as f`.).

Comment: What does n:sqnceItrator mean?(Example 9, line 11)

Comment: @JackyXie: It's a 'slice' operator. It represents a sublist starting at the position of the first argument, and ending just before the last argument. If `lst = [0, 4, 5, 9, 12]`, then `lst[2:4] == [5, 9]`. You can also assign to a slice: `lst[2:4] = [8, 10]` now gives `lst = [0, 4, 8, 10, 12]`.

Comment: @Sjored I thought it was just for strings, forgot how strings and lists work...